# How do i create a table view with additional column and its entries is differ from the source table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Badly need experts' help, as advised to me here in stack is to create a view on table instead. I found same inquiries here but some of those are still unanswered and some are unclear. I just wanted to create a table view for this table where in I want to separate the ClockIn and Clock Out entries. I want also to add different column on my view like time and time_event wherein the entries are different from source table (ST_EmployeePunches). The sample record for time is the time only and time_event is I and O. Please help!

Comment: Your listing of the table is not showing up.  Could you show an example of your current table, and what you want your view to look like?

Comment: Table and Sample Entries of EmployeePunches table.

EmployeeNumber BusinessDate ClockIn    ClockOut
6016257   2012-10-01  2012-10-01 07:20:00 2012-10-01 10:49:00

Comment: Hi erdomke, here's the output i wanted to:

EmployeeNumber | BusinessDate | Time    | Time_Event
6016257  | 2012-10-01 | 07:20:00 | I
6016257  | 2012-10-01 | 10:49:00 | O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify with clearer formatting, what you currently have is

```
EmployeeNumber  BusinessDate  ClockIn              ClockOut
60616257        2012-10-01    2012-10-01 07:20:00  2012-10-01 10:49:00
```

What you want is:

```
EmployeeNumber  BusinessDate  Time                 Time_Event
60616257        2012-10-01    2012-10-01 07:20:00  I 
60616257        2012-10-01    2012-10-01 10:49:00  O
```

You would produce this with a query such as

```
select EmployeeNumber, BusinessDate, ClockIn Time, 'I' Time_Event
from ST_EmployeePunches
union all
select EmployeeNumber, BusinessDate, ClockOut, 'O'
from ST_EmployeePunches
```

Comment: Thank you so much erdomke,.. you save me from here really, you are great.  This is exactly what I am looking for. And I will get the timeonly as Time = CONVERT(CHAR(8),ClockIn,8). THank you so, God bless you.

Comment: Hi erdomke, how will i going to get timeonly from Time header, I cannot use this CONVERT() statement. Please tell me if I should add another post on this. thank you

Comment: Browsing online (e.g. http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=38940), it appears you have several options such as `SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(24), GetDate(), 121), 12, 12)`
and
`SELECT DATEADD(Day, 0-DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate()), GetDate())`

Comment: I got an idea it from your link.. thank you so much with all my heart.
select top 1 EmployeeNumber, BusinessDate, Time=CONVERT(CHAR(10),ClockIn,108), 'I' Time_Event
from ST_EmployeePunches
union all
select top 1 EmployeeNumber, BusinessDate, CONVERT(CHAR(10),ClockOut,108),'O'
from ST_EmployeePunches;